# $\Big| \dfrac{df}{dx}(x)\Big|\leq 5$ for all $x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(0)=0$ and $\Big| \dfrac{df}{dx}(x)\Big|\leq 5$ for all $x$. We can conclude that $f(1)$ is in
>
> 1. $(5,6)$
> 2. $[-5,5]$
> 3. $(-\infty,-5)\cup (5,\infty)$
> 4. $[-4,4]$

The answer would be **2.** (You can also find a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168434/fracdfdxx-leq-5-forall-x-then-f-belong-to-which-interval) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066381/where-does-f1-lies) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352557/f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-is-such-that-f0-0-and-fracdfdxx))

**My question is:** Is there an example of $f$ for which $f(1)$ can be $5$ or $-5$?

For example if we take $f(x)=5\sin x$, $f(1)$ is not $5$(obviously), but we *can not* take $f(x)=5\sin x +c$, where $c\neq 0$, since $f(0)=0$.

Can someone help me here? I am very bad at finding examples. I guess someone has to start with choosing $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=5$, but what would be the next steps? Thanks.

**Added:**

So stupid, thanks to **Kenny Lau**, I understood that. What about if I add an extra condition that $f$ has *non-constant derivative*.

Answer (score 5):

Take $f(x)=5x$ for $5$ and $f(x)=-5x$ for $-5$.

Comment: what the hell !!! I am so stupid.

Comment: Anyway what about if I add non-constant derivative?

Comment: Thanks, I added some extra condition.

Comment: @MANMAID there are no easy examples.

Comment: If derivative is non-constant, then $|f(1)|<5$.

Comment: @Shalop can you prove that?

Comment: Yes because $f(1)=\int_0^1 f'(x)dx$. So if $f(1)=5$, that implies that $f'(x)=5$ a.e (by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693153/show-that-the-integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive), since $5-f' \geq 0$ and $\int (5-f')=0$). Hence $f(x)=5x$. Symmetrically, if $f(1)=-5$, then $f(x)=-5x$.

Comment: @Shalop why don't you write an answer so that I can accept that!

Answer (score 2):

Mean value Theorem:

$\dfrac{f(1) -f(0)}{1-0} = f'(t)$, with $t \in (0,1).$

Hence:

$|f(1)| = |f'(t)| \le 5.$

$\Rightarrow: f(1) \in [-5,5].$

Comment: I know the solution and my question is different.

Comment: Sorry to have missed your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section of Kenny Lau's answer, an user **Shalop** wrote exactly the answer what I wanted, and I think he is right. I told him to post as an answer so that I can accept it, but he did not do that. So, I am writing exactly the same thing what he wrote. (If he reconsiders to an answer in detail, and posts an answer, I will delete my answer!)

---

"...$f(1)=\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)dx$. So if $f(1)=5$, that implies that $f'(x)=5$ a.e (by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693153/show-that-the-integral-of-a-positive-function-is-positive) since $5-f'\geq 0$ and $\int (5-f')=0$). Hence $f(x)=5x$. Symmetrically, if $f(1)=-5$, then $f(x)=-5x$."